# How to find union of two query with distinct id

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have table profile contain status of that profile i.e active and inactive
note there is multiple inactive status record for one csr_id but for sure only one or none record with status active

table for your reference:-

```
id | status    | csr_id |
---+-----------+---------
1  | inactive  |  1
2  | inactive  |  1
3  | inactive  |  1
4  | inactive  |  1
5  | inactive  |  2
6  | inactive  |  2
7  | inactive  |  2
8  | inactive  |  2
9  | active    |  2
```

query for reference:-

```
(select * from profile where csr_id IN (2,1) AND status = 'active') 
    UNION 
 (select DISTINCT ON (csr_id) *from profile where csr_id IN (2,1) AND status = 'inactive') order by status
```

Result:-

```
id  |  status  | csr_id |
-----+----------+---------------+--------
9   | active   |  2
4   | inactive |  1
8   | inactive |  2
```

expected result:-

```
id  |  status  | csr_id |
-----+----------+---------
9   | active   |  2
4   | inactive |  1
```

because csr_id 2 is active then neglect inactive entry for csr_id 2

any solution?

Comment: What is the logic behind this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `distinct on` only:

```
select distinct on (csr_id) p.*
from profile p
order by csr_id, status, id desc
```

The `order by` clause on ascending `active` puts active records first, and then gives priority to the record with the greatest `id`.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=57e2ae6840421a05b2184f1ce0190345)**:

```
id | status   | csr_id
-: | :------- | -----:
 4 | inactive |      1
 9 | active   |      2
```

Comment: Won't work if we have to filter specific csr_id 
like select distinct on (csr_id) p.*
from profile p where csr_id in (1,2)
order by csr_id, status, id desc

Comment: @Adwaitsoni: you can just add a `where` clause to the query, and it will work as expected...

Comment: (order by csr_id,status)  this condition works properly in my case

Comment: Thanks to all for your valuable contribution.